# Binding data to collapsible set in phonegap

Tags: jquery, sql, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

i have a collapsible set to which i am trying to the append query result as the listview. but i am unable to bind the result as listview.

This is what i am trying to do

```
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM FOLDER', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function listdata(tx,results){
    list= ("<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='false' id='mylist' />");
    count = results.rows.length;
    $.each(results.rows,function(index){ 
        var row = results.rows.item(index);
        var li = '<li><a href="#">'+row['Date']+'</a></li>';
        list = $(list).append(li);
    });   
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {    
    $.each(results.rows,function(index){ 
        var row = results.rows.item(index);

        tx.executeSql('SELECT Date FROM ALLIGNMENT WHERE name="'+row[name]+'"', [], listdata, errorCB);

        var div = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsible="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d"><h3>'+
            row["name"]+'<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" data-iconpos="right">10</span></h3></div>';

        $(list).appendTo(div).parent().appendTo('[data-role="content"]').end().trigger("create");
        $('div[data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible({theme:'c',refresh:true});
        $('[data-role="listview"]').listview().listview('refresh'); 
    });
}
```

If i try to display just a collapsible set, i am able to display. but when i try to display the listview nothing is getting displayed. what is the mistake i am doing?

Thanks:)

New function structure

```
function queryDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM FOLDER', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}




 function listdata(tx,resultset){

   list = $("<ul>").attr({'data-role':'listview','data-inset':'false','id':'mylist'});
   count = resultset.rows.length;

    $(list).remove();

   $.each(resultset.rows,function(index){
    var row = resultset.rows.item(index);
   // alert(row['CreatedDate']);
     var li = '<li><a href="#">'+row['Date']+'</a></li>';
    list.append(li); 

    });



div = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsible="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d"><h3>'+
 row1["name"]+'<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" data-iconpos="right">'+count+'</span></h3></div>';
 }
list.appendTo(div).parent().appendTo('[data-role="content"]').end().trigger("create");
$('div[data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible({theme:'b',refresh:true});
$('[data-role="listview"]').listview().listview('refresh'); 

 }


function querySuccess(tx, results) {

$.each(results.rows,function(index){ 

   row1 = results.rows.item(index);

tx.executeSql('SELECT CreatedDate FROM ALLIGNMENT WHERE name="'+row1["name"]+'" ', [], listdata, errorCB);

});

}
```

Comment: Is variable list a global variable?

Comment: @Gajotres yea.. variable list is an global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your function listdata.

jQuery object can't be created like this:

```
list= ("<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='false' id='mylist' />");
```

For start you are missing $ sign before ( but even with that it will not work.

Do it like this:

```
var list = $("<ul>").attr({'data-role':'listview','data-inset':'false','id':'mylist'});
```

Also in this case you don't need to use this line like this:

```
list = $(list).append(li);
```

it will not work, it should look like this:

```
list.append(li);
```

**EDIT :**

You will need to make addition changes. When you execute this line:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT Date FROM ALLIGNMENT WHERE name="'+row[name]+'"', [], listdata, errorCB);
```

call to function listdata is asynchronous. Which means that rest of the code will not wait for this function to run. Basically you will need to move some of this lines:

```
    var div = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsible="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d"><h3>'+
    row["name"]+'<span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" data-iconpos="right">10</span></h3></div>';

    $(list).appendTo(div).parent().appendTo('[data-role="content"]').end().trigger("create");
    $('div[data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible({theme:'c',refresh:true});
    $('[data-role="listview"]').listview().listview('refresh');
```

into the function **listdata**. Currently list is empty because function is still running when you try to append list object.

Comment: i tried to print the value of count = results.rows.length; and i am getting 0 as the count value, so i think control is not entering into  $.each of listdata loop.

Comment: That is why you cant see a listview, it will not show up in case it is empty.

Comment: yea.. but why it is not taking the query result?. I am calling query properly know?

Comment: That is up to you to find out, everything looks fine. Check your query first.

Comment: gajotres because of quotes count was having value zero. i fixed it. but still data is not displaying. controller is running in the loop

Comment: Ok lets test it step by step. First before this line: $(list).appendTo(div)........ test this alert(list.text()); This will show us if listview was populated. Also change this: $(list).appendTo(div).... to this list.appendTo(div).... because list is already jQ object, no point in wrapping it again.

Comment: when i try to print alert(list.text()); i get a error saying "uncaught:typeerror cannot call method 'text' of underfined"

Comment: That would mean that list is not a global variable and list in function querySuccess is just an empty variable. Did you declared var list; out side of your functions?

Comment: i have defined list as global variable. i have defined var name;
var count;
var list; at the begining of my js file

Comment: Let us then try this, try this same line: alert(list.text()); at the end of function listdata. And tell me have you applied changes I told you in my answer?

Comment: i am getting value in listdata method. i tried adding at the end of listdata method. yea. i have followed all the steps u said in your answer

Comment: Damn I forgot another problem. Look at my answer again, I have added new content.

Comment: now list view is displaying. but the all the collapsible set will have the same name. i tried many things but i was not able to make it work properly

Comment: Can you update your question with your new functions, don't remove the old one, just add the new one. I would like to see new structure.

Comment: i have added the new functions.

Comment: Ok lets fix your collapsible name. You can create another global variable called rowName. During the execution of function querySuccess but before the second query set rowName = row1["name"]; Now when second query calls function listdata and when you create a collapsible element use variable rowName  as a collapsible name.